# Do Actions throw exceptions differently?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-3.5

Consider the following code:

```
public void RunScriptBuild()
{
    try
    {
        _helper.RunScriptBuild(); //throws FileNotFoundException
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }
}

private void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    //write to log file
    ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Logging Policy");
}
```

This works perfectly fine and I get a wealth of information written to my log file.
Instead, my actual code is as follows:

```
public void RunScriptBuild()
{
    RunAction(_helper.RunScriptBuild); 
}

private void RunAction(Action task)
{
    try
    {
        task(); //still throws FileNotFoundException
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }
}

private void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    //doesn't write to log file
    ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Logging Policy");
}
```

So now when `RunAction` is called and throws an error, nothing gets written to my log file. Stepping through it, `LogException` **does** get called and I can step over it without problem. I can't step inside HandleException as it's part of the MS Enterprise Application Block. But my boss didn't like how I was doing it and said I need to use more generic methods as they're more flexible, and came up with that second code block here.

I just looked over [MSDN - How to Handle Exceptions thrown by Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but didn't help me much. I'm using .NET 3.5 so I don't have AggregateExceptions available. Can't seem to find much on 'How to Handle Exceptions thrown by Actions'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the fact that the exception is being thrown from a delegate.

It could be related to the fact that you're calling a different actual method, possibly resulting in a different exception being thrown, thus being handled differently, or it could be some change, possibly environmental, that is causing your exception handler to act differently in the two cases for some reason entirely unreleated to the use of a delegate over a direct method call.

Comment: In the end both of the code bases were calling the same function, `_helper.RunScriptBuild` is still ultimately doing the same thing as when I had the `RunScript(string path){Process.Start(path);}` method. Guess I'll just have to try and dig deeper...

Comment: Well, you answered my question so I'll mark this as the solution. The source of my problem was that the framework I'm using requires a particular `using` statement in both the class that *throws* the exception and the class that catches it. So I don't really know why the first block worked and the second one didn't... But I fixed it now I guess.